# Scala Returning a void function with 0 parameters, ugly syntax?

Tags: scala

Given a method defined as follows

```
 def descendEach(times:Int)(f:()=>Unit) {
      for (i <- 1 to times) {
          // other code
          f()
      }
   }
```

when I use this method I want to be able to write

```
 gd.descendEach(20){
    println(gd.cost)
 }
```

but the scala compiler only lets me get away with

```
  gd.descendEach(20){ () => 
    println(gd.cost)
 }
```

which is kind of ugly. Am I missing something here? Is it possible to write it in the first way I presented?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```
def descendEach[T](times:Int)(f: => T)
```

This way you can not only pass function without extra `() =>` (this is called *pass by name*), but also use functions returning any type (not necessarily `Unit`). It is sometimes convenient when you have an existing function you want to pass but don't really care about its return value:

```
def g() = 42
descendEach(20)(g)
```

Note that with this syntax you are simply using `f`, not `f()`.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, that fixed it. For my example, just doing `f: => Unit` works as well, but the Generic version is handy to know.