# Why put a generic type next to a function?

Tags: scala

When I look at Scala libraries I see code like this.  Why put test **[A]** .

```
   def test[A](block : Int => Unit) : Unit = {  
        block(10)
    }     

    test { u =>

        println(u)        
    }
```

This is just as valid I suppose.  It runs the same way.

```
 def test(block : Int => Unit) : Unit = {   
            block(10)
        }
```

I've just been curious what the reasoning(or design pattern) is behind it.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example from a Scala library?  This isn't something I normally see.  (I can't think of a single example.)

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933786

Comment: Thanks! That seems to explain it.

Here is the code where I saw it.

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/db/DB.scala

Specifically the withConnection function.  Although my example doesn't make sense in this case, because I'm supplying the Unit type as the return code for the block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type parameter `A` makes no sense here because it is not used.

```
def test[A](block: Int => A): A = block(10)
```

Here `A` specifies the return type.

Comment: But how is the A next to the function name used?  I see how it is used  as the return block signature.

Comment: @DrewH: What do you mean with "how is the A next to the function name used"? A is inferred by the compiler when you call it. `test { i => new Test(i) }` will create an instance of Test with the given i. The compiler infers Test as type of A.

Answer (score 1):

When there a generic type next to the function, it means that the function is a generic function.

The following is a very simple example:

```
// generic functions which returns type of `A`
def test1[A](x: A) = x
def test2[A](x: => A) = { println("Hello"); x }

val x1 = test1(1)
// x1: Int = 1

val x2 = test1("Hello World")
// x2: java.lang.String = Hello World

val x3 = test2(123.4)
// Hello
// x3: Double = 123.4

val x4 = test2("Test2")
// Hello
// x4: java.lang.String = Test2
```

As you can see, the return type of `test1` and `test2` are determined by the type of their arguments.

The following is another use case.

```
// We could implement `map` function ourself.
// We don't care about what type of List contains,
// so we make it a generic function.
def map[A, B](xs: List[A], f: A => B): List[B] = {
    var result: List[B] = Nil
    for (i <- xs) {
        result ++= List(f(i))
    }
    result
}

// Now use can map any type of List to another List.
map(List("1", "2", "3"), (x: String) => x.toInt)
//res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```